# I ordered chicken, but the restaurant gave me pork. Can I sue them?

Tags: food

I ordered kung pow chicken from a Chinese restaurant. When I ate, I realized that the meat didn't taste like chicken. I called the restaurant and asked what kind of meat they gave me, and they said it was chicken. I hung up and looked at the food, then I realized that the meat looked like pork. I fell throwing up as I am a Muslim and never never eat pork. I called the restaurant again and got the same answer. I didn't eat the food. How do I prove whether it was chicken or pork? Can I sue them if the meat was pork? Thank you.

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in? That will probably significantly affect the answer.

Comment: If you saved the food, you can probably establish that it was pork if indeed it was. This question has been asked and answered: yes, you can sue.

Comment: You would sue for damages. I can understand that while “pork instead of chicken” would be just a small annoyance to _me_, for someone who is Jewish or Muslim it could be a very serious business justifying much higher damages.